# running tcpreplay with docker and boot2docker

Tags: docker, boot2docker, tcpreplay

I'm working on a netflow logger and I want to setup some automated performance testing.  I want to take my testing pcap and replay it to my program from within a docker image running under boot2docker.  The networking side of this is stumping me.

I can access my desktop (the machine hosting the boot2docker vm) from within the docker image running under boot2docker (scp/ssh/netcat all seem to work as expected).  However, when I run tcpreplay on my pcap from within the docker image I never see the traffic on my desktop.

What I've tried:

- rewrite the srcip in the pcap to be the srcip of the docker host
- tcpdump piped through netcat  (netflow is UDP so I don't really care about the connection setup)  The traffic makes it but my program gets some exceptions and dies.  This doesn't surprise me, but it does indicate that I can get the traffic out of the docker vm and into my program.
- I can successfully tcpreplay the pcap to my program from within a normal debian vm

Any ideas on what I need to do to get tcpreplay to send my pcap to my desktop?

Comment: This will be an interesting blog post when you've got it working :)

Comment: can you tell us more about where you're capturing, perhaps enough to reproduce? (I'm kinda curious about the differences in network types - your debian vm has vs b2d.

Comment: diagram of how stuff is setup. http://imgur.com/BhjjdDI
The packets in the pcap have been re-written to be sent towards the OSX host (192.168.1.10 in the diagram).  I'm curious as to wether tcpreplay can work at all within a docker container.  I'm sure it has something to do with the various virtual networks in play, just can't get my head wrapped around how to approach the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try change the destination MAC addr to that of docker0, which is the default VM running. This works for me.

Comment: This will give you the MAC addr to be used:
root@98ae3344c7b5:/# arping -f -I $(ip route show match 0/0 | awk '{print $5, $3}')
ARPING 172.17.0.1 from 172.17.0.2 eth0
Unicast reply from 172.17.0.1 [02:42:65:93:5C:61]  0.692ms
Sent 1 probes (1 broadcast(s))
Received 1 response(s)

Answer (score 0):

For me it's working using a docker bridge:

```
docker network create -d bridge --subnet=192.168.x.0/30
--gateway=192.168.x.1 -o parent=eth0 bridge_net
```

and then you can use a pre-installed docker image with tcpreplay (like https://hub.docker.com/r/dgarros/tcpreplay) and launch as:

```
docker run --net bridge_net --rm -t -v <your_host_folder_pcap_dir>:/data -i dgarros/tcpreplay /usr/bin/tcpreplay --intf1=eth0 <your_pcap_file_located_in_host_folder_pcap_dir>.pcap
```